# NTFS network file copy hangs on +R attrib files / Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cifs, files, attributes

I have encountered at least two server 2008 R2 machines that were recently built that exhibit identical behavior.  When using explorer to copy a folder of files from or to the affected host, any file that is +R (read only) attribute flagged causes the copy to hang for 30 seconds or more before proceeding.

If I enter the folder in command prompt and run attrib -s -h -r * /S, this strips the +R off all files in the tree and they will copy instantly, without any timeout delays.

No errors are being logged.  I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The machine catching the files was running BitDefender AV.  Disabling the AV realtime protection also elminiated the issue. Tested it about 5 times on/off and I'm convinced.